# Quadtree decomposition in MATLAB: qtdecomp function input

Tags: matlab, image-processing, quadtree, decomposition

Does anyone have experience with defining an input function as threshold criterion for the `qtdecomp` function in MATLAB? I tried the following but it did not work:

```
MyFunc = @(A,threshold) std2(A)>threshold;
S = qtdecomp(Image,MyFunc,threshold);
```

Somehow, for some threshold values, only the leftmost quarter of the quadtree is divided into new pieces. Could this maybe be an error in the `qtdecomp` code itself or is there something wrong with my function input?

See the attached image for details. I get this regardless of the threshold I choose:

[image]

Comment: We'd really need to see a sample image. This could be expected behavior for some images. Did you try `qtdecomp` without the custom function?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the image is passed to your anonymous function as an `m x m x k` array representing the image decomposed into `k` blocks. The function must return a vector of length `k`, but `std2` only looks at the first block and returns a scalar. I'm still trying to come up with a vectorized approach to this, but for now here's a simple loop in a standalone function:

```
function v = Std2Func(A, threshold)
   s = size(A,3);
   v = zeros(1,s);

   for k = 1:s
      v(k) = std2(A(:,:,k))>threshold;
   end   
end
```

This iterates through the `k` planes of the input array, applying `std2` to each 2d plane and putting the results into the output vector. Then you just call `qtdecomp` using a handle to the new function:

```
S = qtdecomp(Image,@Std2Func,threshold);
```